# Monitoring RAID with CERC SATA 2s Controller from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raid, monitoring

We've just reinstalled one of our servers with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server. It's got a BIOS RAID system using a CERC SATA 2s Controller. (setup in a RAID 1 config)

How do I monitor the health of my RAID setup from the Ubuntu OS? Is there a utility program i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Dell website - "On Dell PowerEdge SC420 and PowerEdge SC1420 servers, the RAID Storage Manager (RSM) util- ity is used. On Dell PowerEdge 800 and PowerEdge 1800 servers, Dell OpenManageTM Storage Services (OMSS) is used"

I've been looking around for these packages for Ubuntu but can't find them, I know that RHEL has the drivers built in but not the extra tools - basically I think you're out of luck sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear as though Ubuntu is not supported by the Dell [OpenManage](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA) software, but if you can manage to come up with the RPM files that would be needed for your server, you could try to use [alien](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/p/alien) to convert them to DEBs and attempt to install them.  However, this probably won't work, or at least won't completely work.

However, if you don't have dedicated RAID hardware, you could try to use [mdadm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) for software RAID within the OS.  If you can't use the Dell software, and this setup would be acceptable, you could easily use mdadm to monitor the health of the array.